# mysql schema changes with master & slave

Tags: mysql

If I have a MySQL master-slave set-up and I change the schema on the master (e.g. ALTER TABLE/CREATE TABLE, etc), will those changes get replicated over to the slave?

Comment: On latest versions DDL on master will be replicated on the slave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to change it manually.

Comment: CREATE TABLE commands should get replicated. But If you are executing ALTER TABLE like dropping primary key.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is actually that it depends on the type of replication you are using and how your replication setup is configured.

Statement-based replication? 
Applying ALTER TABLE on the master? 
Not using any of the non-replication-safe SQL commands [1] (e.g. non-deterministic functions such as RAND() )?

CREATE and ALTER should replicate just fine.

In some situations it may be useful to stop slave; [run script on master]; [run script on slave]; start slave; An example is here[2].

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html

[2] http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-diffengines.html